# How do I query in mysql to select beetween 4 PM and 10 PM for a whole month

Tags: mysql

So I have a problem to select data from my database. I want to select data with recorded time between 4 PM and 10 PM for a whole month. If it's isn't possible should I query per day for a whole month?

Comment: This isn't a bad question, but you should include the current version of your query or a the schema of your table if you want to get an answer.

Comment: Well, what i've tried so far is
`SELECT * FROM loan WHERE input_date BETWEEN '2019-09-01 16:00:00' AND '2019-09-01 22:00:00'`
And that is as far as i can goes

Comment: But, the answer from @spencer7593 is works

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `mydt` column is DATETIME or TIMESTAMP datatype,

we could do something like this:

```
    FROM t  
   WHERE t.mydt                  >= '2019-09-01'
     AND t.mydt                  <  '2019-09-01' + INTERVAL 1 MONTH
     AND DATE_FORMAT(t.mydt,'%H') >= '16'
     AND DATE_FORMAT(t.mydt,'%H') <  '22'
```

The first two conditions restrict values to the month of September 2019.

The last two conditions restrict the "hour" portion of the datetime, time values from 16:00:00  thru  21:59:99

If we also want to include 22:00:00, we can use `'%T'` as format model in `DATE_FORMAT` and do a less than or equal to comparison

```
     AND DATE_FORMAT(t.mydt,'%T') >= '16:00:00'
     AND DATE_FORMAT(t.mydt,'%T') <= '22:00:00'
```